# Please delete this question [ID 17275214]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question

I do not understand why a perfectly valid question I asked is getting downvoted:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275214/is-it-allowed-in-html5-to-wrap-a-li-inside-an-a-tag/

Please delete the question as the website doesn't allow me to.

Comment: In future, you can do this by using the "flag" button on the post and use the "other" reason to ask a moderator to delete it.

Comment: The answers are nice and I see no reason to delete it really.

Comment: Except that the OP doesn't like to have a negative scoring question sticking around.

Comment: `I do not understand why a perfectly valid question I asked is getting downvoted`.  Like bažmegakapa and others commented:  `-1 - This question does not show any research effort.`  I would imagine that your question would be trivial to test, and combined with your high reputation, is causing quite a backlash.

Comment: I understand you tried to answer your own question making it helpful resource, but it's way too trivial. The question is valid, but in my opinion deserve the downvotes.

Comment: You have 26.1k rep on SO. Why not just suck this one up and be happy about the positively evaluated answers it generated?

Comment: What @LBT said is likely to part of the cause, but your initial (now deleted) comments were quite hostile and I doubt that helped. And if  bažmegakapa is correct in that you are retaliating by downvoting old questions, that's not going to help either.

Comment: You could drastically improve and un-delete your answer.  It wouldn't take many up-votes on an answer to counter the effect of down-votes on a question.

Comment: @LBT: No, his overreaction to my initial comment is what's causing the backlash.

Comment: If the *ANSWERS* are deemed good enough to leave the question posted, does this not in turn make the question good enough?... You guys admitted that the question resulted in useful answers. Why the downvotes? That *IS* what makes a good question...

Comment: @romkyns Nope. Bad questions can have great answers. That doesn't make the question better. It merely means that the answers might end up saving the question.

Comment: @Bart Would the site be better off with or without the question? The consensus seems to be that it's better off with the question, but let's kick the asker in the nuts for asking it. I don't follow :)

Comment: @romkyns The consensus seems to be that the answers shouldn't be deleted. That would happen if the OP got his way with his request to delete the question. We don't necessarily want the question, but possibly are even less interested in losing the answers. P.s. if you like the question, by all means upvote it.

Comment: Yes, the answer is fine, but one could go and ask thousands of questions that can be answered by a small snippet from the spec. The spec is quite long. I don't think this is what this site is for, I think the question should be deleted.

Comment: @Mischa You misunderstand. The OP asked for deletion. I only say we should honor his request. I don't think the question is a candidate for closure, at least the way I understand the current site regulations. But if he wants to delete it, I say we should.

Comment: @bazmegakapa, I see what you mean.

Comment: It's also **a duplicate** or a question **asked today** but was phrased **better** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268834/nesting-html-tags-inside-ul-other-than-li/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Nice find! So I guess this confirms my guess that his rep mattered. He was initially downvoted for daring to ask something so simple with 26k rep (something that only 200 rep users are apparently allowed to do), and then got into further trouble by attempting to discuss the surprising outcome. Great community here :/

Comment: @romkyns Actually, he posted some negative (now deleted) comments targeted at a moderator, in response to the simple question "What does the validator tell you?" He has nobody to blame but himself.

Comment: The question has been deleted. This question would seem to be moot.

Answer (score 12):

Your question was downvoted because it didn't show any research effort (check the downvote tooltip). Had you done a bit of Googling or used a validator, the answer would have been clear to you. I believe you got further flak on this because, as a high reputation user, you probably should know this by now.

Stack Overflow has policies that optimize for good questions; keeping the site interesting and engaging. Basic questions that can be answered by a quick Google don't really add to the site.

I suggest you read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to prevent this from happening in the future.

The reason you can't delete it is because it already has upvoted answers. To me, the question and answers are rather trivial, so I wouldn't mind it being deleted. However, people have put some effort into answering it (and have gotten reputation for it), so it may be wrong to deny them that.

Comment: I’m sorry, but this is not what I was told. StackOverflow was originally explicitly claimed to welcome any and all questions, even basic ones, in order to be a repository of useful questions. I noticed that this exact question wasn’t already on SO, so I asked it. Since I now learned that this is no longer the case and that users are expected to find the answer elsewhere, that is exactly what I will do in future, and SO suffers accordingly.

Comment: @Timwi `[citation needed]`. I don't recall reading that anywhere :/

Comment: It doesn’t matter. With the new attitude, StackOverflow will obviously be less useful. If that is what you guys want, then so be it.

Comment: Erm - this isn't a new attitude, Timwi. It has always been aimed at being a place for **quality** questions and answers, not **any** questions and answers/

Comment: @Timwi Sure, if that's what you think. I somehow doubt that. Also what Rory said.

Comment: @Manishearth see the example at [How do I move the turtle in LOGO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo) and the citation at [Podcast #58](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/podcast-58/) to at least point out that SO was contended by some (semi-official?) parties as allowing very simple easily researchable questions 4 years ago. I'm still surprised that meta users *don't* see how confusing this whole category is for SO users given that...

Comment: @jball Note the date. And that it's closed+locked. Policy has evolved, at least a bit. And the point in the podcast was about _basic_ questions(which are allowed), not easily researchable ones (which are not), though the LOGO question was both. I'm not so sure on SO, but on Physics I can give examples of basic questions that are not easily researchable.

Comment: @Manishearth I understand that it's an old post. The first two comments in this thread are talking about historical positions, not current. And I'm not really trying to debate the nuances what should and shouldn't be allowed, just pointing out the facts that have lead to the current confusion in the minds of some users. As you concede, the turtle question is an easily researched one, so it doesn't preclude the confusion, but rather was part of what has created said confusion.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to disassociate the question from your account - can't say for sure, but the top answer to [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC:WIKI?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki) suggests so.

I've been in this situation before (where I'm not allowed to delete a question I don't like) and it sucks. That is seriously messed up. It is messed up to be told "you've made a mistake, but you aren't allowed to undo it; sorry buddy but you're going to have to sit through this beating".

I say this question should be disassociated from the author's account if it cannot be deleted. No civilised community would tell someone he screwed up but prevent the mistake being corrected, forcing one to endure its consequences.

Comment: Alternatively, get over it, it's just rep. Nobody is taking a "beating".

Comment: Definitely possible. As far as I know, the content license even requires SE staff to comply with such requests.

Comment: Yes, it is messed up, but it's not like the team will refuse requests to disassociate posts either; in fact, we're more than happy to do that. We just don't want to *delete* questions whose answers are worth keeping, but it's the responsibility of the asker to state their request clearly so we know to do exactly what they're looking for.

Comment: @meagar The rep loss is indeed irrelevant, but having 30 people thumb-down you is psychologically quite a beating.

Comment: @romkyns Note that he *gained* 20 rep over-all from the question. It's only now that the question is deleted that he's actually *lost* rep.

Comment: @meagar Glad to see that it got deleted. As I said, I suspect the rep is irrelevant here, judging from my own past experience in a similar situation.