# Change the Help Centre to reflect the new off-topicness of things

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, off-topic, help-center

The [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) section of the Help Centre describes questions that you shouldn't ask on Stack Overflow as being "open-ended", "chatty" etc. It does not mention the new close reasons under off-topic that could be construed to be "programming related", i.e. "on-topic":

> Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

and

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

[Moving these close reasons out of the off-topic one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192086/shouldnt-off-topic-be-only-about-off-topic) is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). Can the Help Centre be updated to include these two close reasons as being off-topic. I'm no wordsmith but (plagiarising heavily) something like the following might be a start:

> Questions should be answerable and show effort; if you have a problem with your code please describe the problem and include code that reproduces it. If you're asking for code please include your solutions, why they didn't work and the expected results.

Robert mentions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196815/why-is-my-question-off-topic-on-stack-overflow-even-though-its-programming-rel) that these are covered by the FAQ but this just says:

> each community decides which specific topics are and are not allowed on their site.
>
> This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined by the community. What's on- and off-topic is not always intuitive, so it may be necessary to reword the question to fit this site's scope after reviewing the community guidelines.
>
> Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope.

and links back to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Here's a related feature request that I made about barely researched questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184961/update-the-dont-ask-page-to-prevent-barely-researched-questions-narqing-the-tu

Comment: Now, *this* is a sane feature-request. Donno about your wording though.

Comment: @Shog9: What about linking http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196815?  Or folding http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196816 into the help center topic?

Answer (score 2):

[Help center/On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) now reads:

> **Some questions are not suitable for Stack Overflow**, even if
>   they fit into one of the categories listed above. To find out why,
>   see:
>
> - [What types of questions should I
>     avoid asking?](/help/dont-ask)
> - [Why are
>     some questions marked "on hold"?](/help/closed-questions)
> - [Why is my
>     question off-topic on Stack Overflow, even though it's
>     programming-related?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196815/)